# Mapping pandas DataFrame rows to a pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas

I need to create a pandas series whose elements are each a function of a row from a DataFrame. Specifically the is a 'metadata' column which is a json string and I want a Series of dicts that are the json plus the rest of the columns. Ideally I would want something equivalent to a map method for a dataframe:

```
df.map(lambda row: json.loads(row.metadata).update({'timestamp':row.timestamp}))
```

(update is destructive and does not return a new dict but you get the point)

EDIT: You can copy this

```
metadata    timestamp
"{'a':1,'b':2}" 000000001
"{'a':1,'c':2}" 000000002
"{'a':1,'c':2}" 000000003
```

And load it with

```
In [8]: import pandas as pd

In [9]: pd.read_clipboard()
Out[9]:
        metadata  timestamp
0  {'a':1,'b':2}          1
1  {'a':1,'c':2}          2
2  {'a':1,'c':2}          3
```

The desired result should be a pandas.Series with the contents of this list:

```
[{"a":1,"b":2,"timestamp":000000001}
{"a":1,"c":2,"timestamp":000000002}
{"a":1,"c":2,"timestamp":000000003}]
```

Comment: Can you post a small example dataset? Ideally this would be something we can copy and then load immediately with `pandas.read_clipboard()` (test it yourself to check)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about to modify the strings?
Something like:

```
new_metadata = df.apply(lambda x: '{}\b,"timestamp":{}}}'.format(x.metadata,x.timestamp),axis=1)
```

Which produces:

```
In [1]: new_metadata
Out[2]: 
0    {'a':1,'b':2,"timestamp":1}
1    {'a':1,'c':2,"timestamp":2}
2    {'a':1,'c':2,"timestamp":3}
```

Comment: You can of course play with strings to produce the zeros of timestamp, I don't know which rules they should follow

Comment: I would rather a key-value map is saved in the series but this works for my specific case. Thank you